# lavaan: No variance in predicted standard errors

Tags: r, standard-error, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I have a question concerning the prediction of factor scores with lavaan. When I try to predict factor scores with my estimated model, I get variance in the factor scores but not in the standard errors. How is that possible? Does lavaan estimate only one SE for all cases in the data?
Below you can find a minimal reproducible example, with which you can look into the problem yourself if you want to/have the time to do so. You may have to run it 2-3 times, if the created sample data doesn't work out.

What I have found is, that lavaan only estimated case wise standard errors if I set the argument `missing = "ml"` in the `lavPredict`-Function, even when there is no missing data (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaan/lavaan.pdf, p. 55-56). However, the casewise calculated SE is just a sequence of the same standard error, that is calculated when I omit the argument (you can see it by commenting out the line).

Or maybe I defined my model structure badly? I want to create a bifactor model with a factor combining the measures and an orthogonal factor for measure_b.

Thank you for the responses

````
library(lavaan)

# Sample Size
N <- 220

# Models
model <- "
TARGET =~ measure_a_01 + measure_a_02 + measure_a_03 + measure_a_04 + measure_a_05 + measure_a_06 + measure_a_07 + measure_a_08

ORTHOGONAL =~ measure_b_01 + measure_b_02 + measure_b_03 + measure_b_04 + measure_b_05 + measure_b_06 + measure_b_07 + measure_b_08

TARGET =~ measure_b_01 + measure_b_02 + measure_b_03 + measure_b_04 + measure_b_05 + measure_b_06 + measure_b_07 + measure_b_08

TARGET ~~ 0*ORTHOGONAL
"

# Introduce fake covariance
lower_add <- -0.5
higher_add <- 5

# ramdom sample data with fake covariance
sample_data <- tibble(
    measure_a_01 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_a_02 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_a_03 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_a_04 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_a_05 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_a_06 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_a_07 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_a_08 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_b_01 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_b_02 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_b_03 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_b_04 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_b_05 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_b_06 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_b_07 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N),
    measure_b_08 = rnorm(N, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.8) + seq(lower_add, higher_add, length.out = N)
)

# Estimating Models
fit_model <- sem(
    model = model,
    estimator = "ml",
    missing = "ml",
    data = sample_data
)

# Predicting Factor scores and standard errors
lavPredict(fit_model, se = "standard")```
````